# pkcs11 cmac calculation in java

Tags: java, wrapper, pkcs#11, hsm, iaik-jce

I am trying to calculate AES-MAC (RFC 4493) with Pkcs11 wrapper in java. and it seems that the hsm sends the last bloc of AES-CBC which is not the expected result.
Here is the how I send my PKCS11 request:

```
            CK_MECHANISM mec = new CK_MECHANISM();
                        
            mec.mechanism = Mechanism.AES_MAC_GENERAL.getMechanismCode();
            mec.pParameter = new MacGeneralParameters(16L).getPKCS11ParamsObject();
            
            cryptoki.C_SignInit(ckiSession, mec, key, true);
            Mac = cryptoki.C_Sign(ckiSession, data);
```

and here is the result:

```
key                   = 00000000000000000000000000000000
data                  = 00000000000000000000000000000000
AES_CBC(key, data)    = 66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2E
cmac(key, data)       = 66E94BD4EF8A2C3B884CFA59CA342B2E
expected cmac         = 763CBCDE81DF9131BF897712C088EDAD
```

Can you please help to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your code uses the `AES_MAC_GENERAL` mechanism which is a CBC-MAC (see [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-curr/v2.40/errata01/os/pkcs11-curr-v2.40-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc441850493) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC#Standards_that_define_the_algorithm)).

For AES-CMAC you should use `CKM_AES_CMAC`/`CKM_AES_CMAC_GENERAL` (see [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-curr/v2.40/errata01/os/pkcs11-curr-v2.40-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc441850512)).

Note that this mechanism might not be supported by your HSM.

Good luck with your project!

EDIT>

I don't have access to IAIK wrapper right now, but given the [javadoc](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/overview-summary.html) you might want to try something like:

```
CK_MECHANISM mec = new CK_MECHANISM();
mec.mechanism = PKCS11Constants.CKM_AES_CMAC_GENERAL;
mec.pParameter = new MacGeneralParameters(16L).getPKCS11ParamsObject();
```

Comment: Thank you, in fact. I think CMAC is not supported by the hsm (or the iaik wrapper). I didn't found AES-CMAC in Mechanism attributes list.

Comment: @zero See my updated answer for setting the `CKM_AES_CMAC_GENERAL` mechanism (`CKM_AES_CMAC` without parameter is worth trying as well). HSM support for particular mechanism is in the vendor provided documentation and can be queried using [`C_GetMechanismList`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html#_Toc235002331). A firmware update might be needed.

Comment: Thank you a lot !! it works !! (using CKM_AES_CMAC) :D :D

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind. Do you know if it's possible to encrypt a key k1 in the hsm with another key k2 in the same hsm with PKCS11 ?

Comment: @zero Have a look at [C_WrapKey](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html#_Toc235002393) call ([here](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/wrapper/PKCS11.html#C_WrapKey-long-iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.CK_MECHANISM-long-long-boolean-) is a IAIK wrapper javadoc). I am glad it works.